# An unhandled exception of type System.StackOverflowException occurred in my.dll?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, dll, eigen

I have been developing a process which works under c++ and needs to be called from a webservice in c#.

In the first version of the program a c# program successfully works with a c++ dll consisting of several classes and one ref class with static function.

After this, I have crated a WCF web service and ported my code:

C# webservice calling function:

```
try
{
    StringBuilder d = new StringBuilder(1000);
    fixed (byte* pt = shelfImage)
    {
        vf.Operations.IdentifyBrands(pt, (int)shelfImage.Length, rowCount, columnCount, d);
    }
    Logger.log("Result is: " + d.ToString());
    return d.ToString();
}
```

C++ DLL part:

```
//Importing GMM and elm data
std::string dataDir = "C:\\VisionFetchData\\";
FeatureExtractor fx;
fx.loadGMM(dataDir+"gmmCigarette.yml");
ELMClassifier* elm = new ELMClassifier(dataDir + "elmv3.bin");

//extracting features and identifying brands
std::vector<float> shelfFeatures = fx.processShelf(mImg, detected);
std::vector<int> ids = elm->classify(shelfFeatures);
```

Program works successfully **until last line** and crashes on classify function **before** even entering the function body. ShelfFeatures are expected to have 50K-1M size. Classifier function uses call by reference in order to save up memory.

I'm using eigen library in ELMClassifier class and that's why I have to use ELMClassifier* and new keyword. I also used EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW parameter in public part of the definition of the class.

I have tried:

- removing call by reference on classifier function
- removing EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW and class pointer definition
- calling classifier with a vector of 0 size(should return empty vector)

What could have caused this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to debug further. Catch the exception and examine, look at the Stacktrace and examine further. 
You say the exception is thrown before classify is entered ... That makes it seem like the usual function call procedure (such as pushing arguments on the stack, incrementing pointers, ... ) caused it. But you said that shelfFeatures is passed as reference, so that makes it kind of unlikely. Are you sure it's passed as reference? 

And yea, you have to examine the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two-fold problem here. First, the default .exe stack size is 1mb. So, your `shelfFeatures` variable is already storing a large part of that, *on top* of the stack servicing your C# managed code. You're playing a dangerous game with memory allocation, even more so since `elm->classify` returns a *copy* which is then copied *again* to `ids`. You're effectively doubling the amount of memory at a single point in time -- no wonder your stack is overflowing! Furthermore, you're doing the same thing when you create `shelfFeatures` -- it's copied over from a function call.

You have a couple choices. First, allocate on the heap and don't forget to destroy afterwards. Alternatively, you can set the stack size of your executable [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx).

Comment: I don't think that's the right answer because firstly, the "elmv3.bin" is a  huge file(300MB) and stores it on the memory, mush be heap. Secondly, 'shelfFeatures' have a size of 327680, which is by your definition, exceeds stack size by itself, but program proceeds. Third, from what I know, vectors are not copied if you use them with "call by reference".
If you say that "function parameters are allocated on the stack and therefore should be smaller than 1M", I understand. However as I say, all vectors are passed by reference to the functions for avoiding the copy overhead.

Comment: The vector passed into the function is passed by reference yes, but the vectors you return are passed onto the stack as a copy and then copied over. And the heap is much larger, 2 GB per exe unless you specify it to take more.

Comment: I have tried passing an **empty** vector, which gave same exception. After you advice of not passing parameters, I converted call by reference routines to pointers, which didn't solve the problem. Perhaps an Eigen issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the problem, nothing to do with Eigen or call by reference. Just stack space.

Apparently, statically allocated variables took space on stack and an array of 100000 elements proves a problem to it. Changed my internal array(have to be static) to a managable(500) size and problem resolved.

Thank you all for your help.